# SortedSet::removeAll( headSet ) fails, but deriving another collection from headSet succeeds. Why?

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification, treeset, sortedset

From a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)) in Java 8:

1. I call the [`::headSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet-E-) method to get a `SortedSet` of the objects at the front of the sorted collection.
2. I call `::removeAll` to delete those frontmost objects.
   BAM, throws a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Yet if I make another SortedSet from the headSet and pass that derived set to the `::removeAll`, no problem.

Why?

Demo code using Java 8 Update 45. Enable the line `//sortedSet.removeAll( headSet );` to see the exception thrown.

```
String cockatiel = "Cockatiel";

SortedSet sortedSet = new TreeSet< String >( );
sortedSet.add( "Dog" );
sortedSet.add( "Cat" );
sortedSet.add( "Bird" );
sortedSet.add( "Elephant" );
sortedSet.add( cockatiel );  // Passing var rather than literal.
sortedSet.add( "Guppy" );

System.out.println( "Before: " + sortedSet );

// Direct way. FAIL
SortedSet< String > headSet = sortedSet.headSet( cockatiel );
System.out.println( "headSet: " + headSet );
//sortedSet.removeAll( headSet );  // Fails. Throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.

// Derived way. PASS
SortedSet<String> headSetDerived = new TreeSet<String>( headSet); // Make a TreeSet from a TreeSet.
sortedSet.removeAll( headSetDerived );  // Succeeds. Why?

System.out.println( "After: " + sortedSet );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## headSet Backed By Original Set

In the first method, you're modifying the set (by removing elements) at the same time as iterating over it (to get the elements to remove). That throws the exception. Remember that the head set is backed by the original set, so modifying the original set ends up modifying the head set -- which you can't do while iterating over that head set.

Excerpt from [`TreeSet::headSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet-E-) doc (emphasis in bold is mine):

> **Returns a view** of the portion of this set…. The **returned set is backed by this set**, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa.

## Workarounds

There are generally two ways to get around this. One is to use an Iterator directly and use its `remove()` method. The other is to separate the iteration and modification by first iterating to create a copy of the set and then iterating over the copy to remove from the original; this is what you did in your second approach.

Comment: I did not realize the headSet is backed by the original Set. I see that now in the doc. That explains this behavior, where the first deletion succeeds while further deletions throw the exception. Thanks.